# Selenium, Maven, Jenkins: Updated /new test cases do not run through eclipse. The changes only appeared after running the script from Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, jenkins

I have automated my test cases using Selenium, Maven and Jenkins. And I am facing following issue:

For example: I create a class `test.java` which contains 5 test cases. I run the test case from eclipse, it works. Then I run it from Jenkins, it works fine.

Then I add two more test cases and try to run the total 7 test case. BUT this time, eclipse will run only 5 test case. It will not run all 7 test cases until I run it from Jenkins.

I have CLEAN and BUILD the project. But it is not working for me and keep running the previous test cases.

Comment: How you are executing ur test from eclipse ? maven pom or testNG xml?

Comment: Dear I am using testNG

Comment: How does you pom file look like and how are you calling Maven?

Comment: Nothing special in POM.  It has following dependencies 
<artifactId>testng</artifactId>
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
 <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
<artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
 <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>

Answer (score 0):

You cancheck out the .project file and compare it with previous version. That might help